# Bottom up Construction heaps

Tags: heap

I'm an working on a question where I have 10 keys and I have to make a bottom up construction. According to my book, I'm supposed to construct (n+1)/2 heaps which is 11/2=5.5 heaps for the bottom. Then 11/4 for the 2nd level, 11/8 for 3rd and so on.

The problem is I get this as result:

(Using 'a' for example)

[image: picture of heaps]

Since 11/2=5.5, so I round to 6, 11/4=2.75 so 3, 11/8=1.375 so 2, and 11/16=0.6875 so 1.

Even if I don't round up, I still have a weird heaps. Can anyone explain where I messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up because only the last layer in a binary heap is allowed to not be full. A heap with 10 elements should look like this:

```
        1
     /     \
    2       3
   /  \    / \
  4    5  6   7
 /\   /
8  9  10
```

As for the bottom up construction you don't need to think too much about the amount of heaps. The basic idea is that

1. Nodes with no children are trivial heaps.
2. If a node has two heaps as children we can convert it to a larger heap with a bubbling operation.

So at the start we know that the nodes in the 4th layer (8, 9 and 10) are already heaps. We can then use this to bubble the nodes in the third layer to turn them into heaps as well and so on.

Comment: I understand the right answer is that but how can i get that result with the formula i used? Or maybe another formula to achieve that?

Comment: I'm guessing that formula is only supposed to work for full heaps (ie.: n = 2^k - 1)

Comment: The question gave me a sequence of 10 keys and asked me to make the heaps with bottom up construction. How am I supposed to make it if I can't use the formula?

Comment: I actually explained that. Place the keys in the tree in the posiutions shown but in the same order you got them. The tree is not a heap yet but you know the 4th layer is already trivially heapified. You then do the bubbling operations to heapify the third row and then the second row and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I had 36 12 29... I'd put 36 on top then 12 and 29 on 2nd lvl? Then using heap property I'd switch 36 with 12, making 12 the root?

Comment: Yes, you put 36 on top and so on. However you need to heapify *bottom-up* so you apply the heap property to whatever is in position 5 (n/2; the last guy w/ children) then position 4 and so on. (If you apply the heap property to the top you don't get very far because the subtrees are not heapified yet...)